# Number generation by retrieving data from database

Tags: postgresql

I am working with PostgreSQL. Now I want to generate a number like as register number. It is a 16 digit code.
format: `vvvvvv0000iiiiii`

where, v is the village code which is retrieved from table named village_details (field: village_code).
Then next four digit is fixed as zero.

Then the next 6 digits(ie: `iiiiii`) is customer id (which must increment from `0000001` to `iiiiii`).
Example:

```
1212450000111111    
1212450000111112
```

etc..

How it will be generated?

Comment: So where does that "customer id" come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a sequence for the customer_id:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE customer_id;
```

Then:

```
SELECT village_code || '0000' || lpad(nextval('customer_id'), 6, '0') FROM village_details;
```

Comment: That will return a different customer_id each time you run that `select`statement.

Comment: Yes, I thought this was what was needed... should it return some fixed value then?